# Why does simply adding a library that isn't being referenced cause Meteor code to fail

Tags: mongodb, meteor, ethereum

I have a very basic question about Meteor on Cloud9 and the ethereum library. I am using the Cloud9 IDE. When I create a new Meteor workspace, there are three pre-existing files comprising a small sample app. When I test them, they run as expected. After I install
the ethereum library : meteor add ethereum:web3, the small app no longer works, even without any modification of the files, giving this error:

Started MongoDB.
Unexpected mongo exit code null. Restarting

I don't understand why simply installing a library that isn't even being referenced would cause the code to fail.

Comment: Could it be insufficient RAM? Can you try it on a VM with more RAM?

Comment: Not likely if I'm not even referencing the library, but I've found discussion of similar by other users on the cloud9 website, and I don't think they've resolved it.